# Error installing vim

Tags: 14.10, gnome-terminal, vim, unicode, utf-8

I am running Ubuntu 14.04, as Xubuntu, in an AMD 64 pc, configured as dual boot with Windows 7. I tried installing vim with this:

This was the output:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: Is something already installing without you knowing?

Comment: Which code did you execute to try and install vim? Which code produced the error when run?

Comment: Who ever given -ve vote , give an explanation.

Comment: You must be very persuasive.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please search for your answer before posting your question. In many cases your question has been asked and answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are usually at least 2 common reasons:

1. Either you aren't executing this command as root (typing `id` shows you who you're logged in as or
2. Something else is managing packages at the same time you're trying to install a new one.

To verify if there's anything else managing packages at this time, run `ps -ef | grep dpkg` - if you get `dpkg` processes in the output, just wait a bit and retry after they're gone.

Make sure to attempt the installation as root via:

```
sudo aptitude install vim
```